# Drawing hline based on the current price

Tags: pine-script

I would like to draw a `hline` base on the current price. I know the current price can come from the `close` series but I cannot convert the last value of the serie to a simple float which is the required type for the price.

```
//@version=4
study("Current price + 42", overlay=true)

hline((close + 42), color=color.orange, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
```

Those lines give me this error that I understand like "give me a float, not a serie":

`Cannot call 'hline' with arguments (series[float], color=const color, linestyle=const integer); available overloads: hline(input float, const string, input color, input integer, input integer, const bool, string) => hline`

Comment: Which bar should your horizontal line start from?

Comment: Would like to draw a take profit like bar which will move according the current price. Start from the current price.

Comment: Horizontal lines cannot move. You need to use the function `plot` or `line.new`.

Comment: Is there a way to draw the hline based on the last bar value's close when the indicator is placed? Basically get the currently displayed last bar's close price and draw a hline at that price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mimic a [hline()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_hline) like this:

```
//@version=4
study("MoveLine", overlay=true)

offset = input(42)

var line myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=color.orange, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)

y = close + offset

// Move line
line.set_xy1(myLine, time,     y)
line.set_xy2(myLine, time + 1, y)
```

Which yields this:

[image]

You could also use a function to move the line:

```
//@version=4
study("MoveLine", overlay=true)

offset = input(42)

f_hline(_line, _y) =>
    line.set_xy1(_line, time,     _y)
    line.set_xy2(_line, time + 1, _y)

var line myLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.both, color=color.orange, style=line.style_dashed, width=1)

// Move line
f_hline(myLine, close + offset)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example is given to you:

```
/@version=5
indicator("CurrentPrice Line", overlay = true)

backward_offset = 42
current_offset = 0

current = close[current_offset]

close_line = line.new(bar_index[backward_offset], current, bar_index, current, color = color.orange, width = 2)
line.delete(close_line[1])
```

`line.new()` project is an excellent solution to draw a line.

> Note: you need to delete close[1], which means to delete the line drawn based on the previous price.

Below are several videos that may help you get more details about it.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gmhM5DAV0Q&t=1s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGZI5BmUJBM

And of course, you can learn from the official documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Lines_and_boxes.html